# How to get the color property value defined in <style> tags using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the code below. As you can see I want to retrieve the color value property that I have assigned inside the  tags. Is that possible? Does it depend on the browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      #foo {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="foo">Lorem ipsum</h1>
     <script>
      console.log(document.getElementById("foo").style.color);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't think you can get it using Javascript

Comment: get style from tag style is possible , but if style is defined in other files, js don't know  about  content this files. I reccommend use getComputedStyle()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get style of elemet:  `console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("foo")).color)`
function getComputedStyle return all css styles. Color in this function has different forms: may be rgb() or #RGB, depend of your browser